# Group data by column value

Tags: python

I'm trying to make my life at work a little easier. My data is a parts list and consists of the columns part, component, variant and quantity. If a variant is chosen only the parts with the corresponding variant and the parts without a variant are used. I need to calculate the demand for all components based on current sales.

Example data:

| part | component | variant | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | C1 |  | 1 |
| P1 | C2 | A | 5 |
| P1 | C3 | B | 2 |
| P1 | C4 |  | 4 |

The result should be the following (parts list for each variant):

| part | component | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1-A | C1 | 1 |
| P1-A | C2 | 5 |
| P1-A | C4 | 4 |
| P1-B | C1 | 1 |
| P1-B | C3 | 2 |
| P1-B | C4 | 4 |

I was thinking about combining the columns part & variant but the default components without variant would be missing.

Can someone point me to some keywords I should be looking into so solve my problem? I honestly don't even know what to look for (hence the title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fill the empty "variant" cells with all possible variants
2. Convert the variant column to `list` and `explode`
3. Construct "part" as needed and drop "variant"

```
variants = "".join(df["variant"].dropna().unique().tolist())
df["variant"] = df["variant"].fillna(variants).apply(list)

output = df.explode("variant").reset_index(drop=True)
output["part"] = output["part"] + "-" + output["variant"]
output = output.drop("variant", axis=1)

>>> output

   part component  quantity
0  P1-A        C1         1
1  P1-B        C1         1
2  P1-A        C2         5
3  P1-B        C3         2
4  P1-A        C4         4
5  P1-B        C4         4
```